The parameters are not sent to me in Postman through the body
I'm trying to send some parameters, with files through postman. And I wanted to do it for the body to include files. But, I don't receive any. The Backend is made in Laravel and I log to see the content and I get an empty array of the request that arrives.
I need help on how to get the parameters. I don't think it's a problem with Postman, because I also tried with ThunderClient, and the same thing happens. Otherwise, what other way of sending a file could I use?
I would like to comment that if I send parameters by params (which are placed in the URL), they do
arrive. So, the problem that remains is to send the file.
Este es el codigo que utilizo para verificar:
        Log::info($request->all());
        if ($request->hasFile('pet_image')) {
            Log::info('aaaaa');
            storeMediaFile($pet, $request->file('pet_image'), 'pet_image');
        }

The first log is an empty array, and the second is not displayed because it does not detect the file I passed.
How to send a file via Postman or ThunderClient, and have a backend in Laravel receive it

Are you using POST method?

@ffflabs I am using PUT method

PHP Handles PUT file uploads differently than POST requests. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php. I'd advise modifying your endpoint to use POST instead

@ffflabs It already works, thank you
